# if statement in a funcion with dplyr verbs

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, tidyverse

Is it possible to write something like this:

```
g <- function(method) {
  dataset %>%
    if (method == 1) {
      mutate(boot1 = some_formula1)
    } else {
      mutate(boot2 = some_formula2)
    }
}

a <- g(1)
```

Or is the only choice to use `ifelse` / `if_else` or `case_when` inside mutate?

Comment: Welcome to SO (you're still _kinda_ new here :-)! It would help to know what you're really trying to accomplish with a full, but minimal, working example. Given the sparse info you've provided, @Marcel_G's answer should help but I'm not sure we really know what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hello, yes I am new here. I wanted to post my function (all of it) but then thought that it was not necessary. You guys have solved my problem now, but next time I will try to post exactly what I try to accomplish. So my understanding is that one cannot use an if-statement in the middle of a pipeline and I can stop the pipeline and restart after my if statement.

Comment: Hi again, I have now included all of my code in another question. Can you please look at it [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53498238/if-statement-in-a-function-using-purrr-and-dplyr-list-column-workflow-in-r)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think so, and maybe this could help. If I've understood well, you need to add a new column to an existing dataset (maybe a `data.frame`) with the method as condition:

```
# some fake data
data <- data.frame(a = c(1,3,5))

g <- function(method){
  if (method == 1) {
    data %>% mutate(boot1 = 'some_formula1')} 
  else{
    data %>% mutate(boot1 = 'some_formula2')
                   }
                     }

g(2)
  a         boot1
1 1 some_formula2
2 3 some_formula2
3 5 some_formula2

g(1)
  a         boot1
1 1 some_formula1
2 3 some_formula1
3 5 some_formula1
```

You can put it also in a `dplyr` chain as you stated, maybe like this, with `if_else`:

```
method <- 1
data %>% mutate(boot1 = if_else( method == 1,'some_formula1','some_formula2' ))
```

Or with `case_when`:

```
data %>% mutate(boot1 = case_when(method == 1 ~ 'some_formula1',
                                  method == 2 ~ 'some_formula2'))
```

Despite they seem slower, looking at this (added also `ifelse`):

```
Unit: microseconds
      expr     min      lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
        if 581.548 594.774 636.6556 606.7210 642.9875  980.907   100 a  
   if_else 729.174 747.734 852.2972 772.0545 834.3475 5406.721   100  bc
    ifelse 701.441 716.587 793.0887 743.0400 793.6010 1486.934   100  b 
 case_when 858.454 876.161 931.2391 900.2675 936.5345 1602.134   100   c
```

Comment: Thanks alot! Now the answer seems obvious and my problem was that I did not know when to start to pipe the data.

Comment: Hi again, I cannot implement the if-statement in my function. I have postet a new question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53498238/if-statement-in-a-function-using-purrr-and-dplyr-list-column-workflow-in-r). Can you please look at it?

Answer (score 0):

welcome to stackoverflow. Yes, it is possible to use dplyr-verbs inside a function. Here is your desired function:

```
g <- function(method, data){
  if (method == 1) {
    data %<>% mutate(boot1 = "A")} 
  else{
    data %<>% mutate(boot1 = "B")
  }
  return(data)
}
```

I would suggest to turn the data you are providing into in argument of the function, as well as the method argument. Afterwards you can just add whatever you want to mutate. In my example`g(1, data)` would add a column called boot1 with the value "A". Ofcourse you could to any other transformation.

Comment: Thank you. It seems that the return statement does something with the code so the function does not work.

Comment: You are welcome. The 'return' is just printing the result to the console. It's working fine for me with several datasets like mtcars and iris.

Comment: Hi again. I have asked another question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53498238/if-statement-in-a-function-using-purrr-and-dplyr-list-column-workflow-in-r). When I try to implement the if statement the function does not work. In my original function I use map2 with mutate and I need the if statement if the middle of the pipeline.