# if-statement in a function using purrr and dplyr (List Column Workflow) in R

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, purrr, rlang

I am trying to estimate differences in means for two hospitals, A and B. Every hospital has different "groups" and I have given them group 1 and 2 in the simulated data set. That is I want to test difference in means between hospital A and B within group 1 and group 2 and in addition I have more than one variable (e.g. value1 and value2). So I have to test value1 between hospital A and B within the groups 1 and 2. Even though I specify method=1 in the call at the end I get the third method (the else part). I am using the infer package for the bootstraping (part of tidyverse or tidymodels).

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(readxl)
library(infer)
library(stringr)
library(rlang)

set.seed(1)
A <-data.frame(value1=rnorm(n = 1000, mean = 0.8, sd = 0.2), value2= rnorm(n=10 ,mean=1, sd=0.3)) 
A$hosp <- "A"
A$group <- sample(1:2,nrow(A) , replace=T) 

B= data.frame(value1 = rnorm(n=1200, mean =1 , sd = 0.2), value2= rnorm(n=15, mean=1.1, sd=0.4))
B$hosp <- "B"
B$group <- sample(1:2,nrow(B) , replace=T) 

forskel <- bind_rows(A, B) %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  nest()

rm(A, B)
```

Bellow is my function.

```
bootloop <- function(dataset, procestid, method, reps = 4, alpha = 0.05) { 
  procestid <- enquo(procestid)

  diff_mean <- dataset %>% 
    mutate(diff_means  = map(data, function(.x){.x %>% 
        group_by(hosp) %>% 
        summarise(mean(!!procestid, na.rm=TRUE)) %>% 
        pull() %>% 
        diff() })) %>%
    select(-data)


  bootstrap <- dataset %>% 
    mutate(distribution =map(data, function(.x){ .x %>% 
        specify(as.formula(paste0(quo_name(procestid), "~ hosp")) ) %>% 
        generate(reps = reps, type = "bootstrap") %>%
        calculate(stat = "diff in means", order = c( "A", "B"))} )) %>% 
    inner_join(diff_mean, by="group")  

  if (method==1) {
    bootstrap2 <- bootstrap %>% mutate(Bias_Corrected_KI=map2(distribution, diff_means, function(.x, .y){ .x %>% 
        summarise( l =quantile(.x$stat,pnorm(2*qnorm(sum(.x$stat >= .y)/reps) + qnorm(alpha/2))),
                   u= quantile(.x$stat,pnorm(2*qnorm(sum(.x$stat >= .y)/reps) + qnorm(1-alpha/2)))    )}))  }
  if (method==2) {
    bootstrap2 <- bootstrap %>% mutate(Percentile_KI = map(distribution, function(.x){.x %>% 
        summarize(l = quantile(stat, alpha/2),
                  u = quantile(stat, 1 - alpha/2))}))  }
  else {
    bootstrap2 <- bootstrap %>% mutate(SD_KI =map2(distribution, diff_means, function(.x,.y){.x %>% 
        get_confidence_interval(level = (1 - alpha), type="se", point_estimate = .y)})) 
  }
return(bootstrap2)

}

procestimes <- list("value1", "value2")


a <- map(syms(procestimes), bootloop , dataset=forskel, method=1 ,  reps=1000)
a
```

Even though I specify method=1 in the call I get the third form of confidence interval in the else statement.

```
[[1]]

# A tibble: 2 x 5
  group data                 distribution         diff_means SD_KI           
  <int> <list>               <list>               <list>     <list>          
1     1 <tibble [1,086 x 3]> <tibble [1,000 x 2]> <dbl [1]>  <tibble [1 x 2]>
2     2 <tibble [1,114 x 3]> <tibble [1,000 x 2]> <dbl [1]>  <tibble [1 x 2]>

[[2]]
# A tibble: 2 x 5
  group data                 distribution         diff_means SD_KI           
  <int> <list>               <list>               <list>     <list>          
1     1 <tibble [1,086 x 3]> <tibble [1,000 x 2]> <dbl [1]>  <tibble [1 x 2]>
2     2 <tibble [1,114 x 3]> <tibble [1,000 x 2]> <dbl [1]>  <tibble [1 x 2]>
```

Comment: It seems you have a couple of problems, try to put  `fun <- function(dataset, procestid, method, reps , alpha)`, and also use `==` instead of `=` in `if (method=1)` and `if (method=1)`. Also you are using some soft-deprecated function of `rlang`, try to avoid them. With those correction it seems working, `fun (forskel, value1, method=1, reps = 4, alpha = 0.05)`, but I do not know if it's the desired result: if not, update the question replacing the code, trying to be minimal.

Comment: Hi again thanks! Well the `=` insted of `==` was embarrassing. It has helped alot but when I run `bootloop (forskel, value1, method=1, reps = 4, alpha = 0.05)` (I have changed the name of the function) I should get the Bias_Corrected_KI and not SD_KI which is in the "else" part..

Comment: If I run `bootloop(forskel, value1, method=1, reps = 10, alpha = 0.05)` I get the third kind of confidence interval but when I run `bootloop(forskel, value1, method=2, reps = 10, alpha = 0.05)` I get the correct output. Seems that the code does not capture the first if statement with method ==1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you forget to nest the if statements, try this:

```
bootloop <- function(dataset, procestid, method, reps = 4, alpha = 0.05) { 
  procestid <- enquo(procestid)

  diff_mean <- dataset %>%
    mutate(diff_means  = map(data, function(.x){.x %>%
        group_by(hosp) %>%
        summarise(mean(!!procestid, na.rm=TRUE)) %>%
        pull() %>%
        diff() })) %>%
    select(-data)

  bootstrap <- dataset %>%
    mutate(distribution =map(data, function(.x){ .x %>%
        specify(as.formula(paste0(quo_name(procestid), "~ hosp")) ) %>%
        generate(reps = reps, type = "bootstrap") %>%
        calculate(stat = "diff in means", order = c( "A", "B"))} )) %>%
    inner_join(diff_mean, by="group")

  if (method==1) {
    bootstrap2 <- bootstrap %>% mutate(Bias_Corrected_KI=map2(distribution, diff_means, function(.x, .y){ .x %>% 
        summarise( l =quantile(.x$stat,pnorm(2*qnorm(sum(.x$stat >= .y)/reps) + qnorm(alpha/2))),
                   u= quantile(.x$stat,pnorm(2*qnorm(sum(.x$stat >= .y)/reps) + qnorm(1-alpha/2)))    )}))  }
  else {  # here you should open a curly brackets with else, and close it of course
  if (method==2) {
    bootstrap2 <- bootstrap %>% mutate(Percentile_KI = map(distribution, function(.x){.x %>% 
        summarize(l = quantile(stat, alpha/2),
                  u = quantile(stat, 1 - alpha/2))})) }
  else {
    bootstrap2 <- bootstrap %>% mutate(SD_KI =map2(distribution, diff_means, function(.x,.y){.x %>% 
        get_confidence_interval(level = (1 - alpha), type="se", point_estimate = .y)})) 
  }}
  return(bootstrap2)

}
```

With results:

```
bootloop (forskel, value1, method=1, reps = 4, alpha = 0.05)
# A tibble: 2 x 5
  group data                 distribution     diff_means Bias_Corrected_KI
  <int> <list>               <list>           <list>     <list>           
1     1 <tibble [1,086 x 3]> <tibble [4 x 2]> <dbl [1]>  <tibble [1 x 2]> 
2     2 <tibble [1,114 x 3]> <tibble [4 x 2]> <dbl [1]>  <tibble [1 x 2]> 
> bootloop (forskel, value1, method=2, reps = 4, alpha = 0.05)
# A tibble: 2 x 5
  group data                 distribution     diff_means Percentile_KI   
  <int> <list>               <list>           <list>     <list>          
1     1 <tibble [1,086 x 3]> <tibble [4 x 2]> <dbl [1]>  <tibble [1 x 2]>
2     2 <tibble [1,114 x 3]> <tibble [4 x 2]> <dbl [1]>  <tibble [1 x 2]>
> bootloop (forskel, value1, method=3, reps = 4, alpha = 0.05)
# A tibble: 2 x 5
  group data                 distribution     diff_means SD_KI           
  <int> <list>               <list>           <list>     <list>          
1     1 <tibble [1,086 x 3]> <tibble [4 x 2]> <dbl [1]>  <tibble [1 x 2]>
2     2 <tibble [1,114 x 3]> <tibble [4 x 2]> <dbl [1]>  <tibble [1 x 2]>
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes the problem was in the `else if` which was missing. Is it not easier to simply write `else if` insted of a nested `else` as you do? That is: `if (method==1) {something1} else if (method==2) {something2} else {something3}`. Anyway thanks alot!.

Comment: You are welcome! I'm sorry, but I think not, generally you should nest the if - else conditions, also if you use the `dplyr::if_else`, or `base::ifelse`, but also in MSExcel for example if you use `=IF(X;Y;Z)`, or in SQL with case when (in general)  you ought to nested it. Maybe if you post another question with a simpler and more theoric example, someone can help you.